# How to Count the all <w:p> nodes(inside <w:body>)of my current Node using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is my Xml File

```
<w:body> <w:p><w:r><w:t>para1</w:t></w:r></w:p>
 <w:p><w:r><w:t>para2</w:t></w:r></w:p>
 <w:p><w:r><w:t>para3</w:t></w:r></w:p>
 <w:p><w:r><w:t>para4</w:t></w:r></w:p>
 <w:p><w:r><w:t>para5</w:t></w:r></w:p>
 <w:tbl><w:tr><w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>para6</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>

 <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>para7</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>   <!-- Assume This
 is my Current Node -->

 <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>para8</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>
              </w:tr> </w:tbl> </w:body>
```

So, Now i want to get the count of all `<w:p>` inside `<w:body>` and also previous `<w:p>` of the current node inside `<w:tbl>`. So, For this scenario, my Expected count is 7 at this time...

how i do it?help me to get this...

Comment: Can you please make the question clear?  What count are you mentioning?

Comment: @Mr.K::Question edited...Hope , Ranga think like that...

Comment: You have a simple work-around :) Count all <w:p>'s using length of doc.selectNodes(XPath), referring from root. From the point of selected node, now just count the remaining ones. Find the difference.  I know this is not a respected solution, but its a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count($vtheNode/preceding::w:p)
```

where `$vtheNode` is your node.

**XSLT (both 1.0 and 2.0) solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:w="w:w">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vtheNode" select=
    "/w:body/w:tbl/w:tr/w:tc[last()]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="count($vtheNode/preceding::w:p)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (with namespace defined to make it well-formed):

```
<w:body xmlns:w="w:w">
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>para1</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>para2</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>para3</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>para4</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>para5</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:tbl>
        <w:tr>
            <w:tc>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>para6</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>para7</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <!-- Assume This  is my Current Node -->
            <w:tc>
                <w:p>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:t>para8</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:tc>
        </w:tr>
    </w:tbl>
</w:body>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
7
```

**Do note**: Because the `preceding::` and `ancestor::` axes are not overlapping, a more general solution that doesn't depend on the structure of the document and takes into account the possibility that some of the wanted to count nodes could be ancestors, is:

```
count($vtheNode/preceding::w:p | ($vtheNode/ancestor::w:p)
```